# Iterating a multidimensional string array with speed

Tags: c#, unsafe

I'm trying to work out the fastest way to iterate a multidimensional C# array. I have stripped out all the domain code to focus on the problem.  At the moment, this executes in 1.86 seconds, performing about 25,000,000 iterations in that time, processing 5000 array elements.  I'm setting myself the goal of bring 1.86s down as much as I can in 2 days :-)

In the real world, it'll be more like 50,000² to process.

I have tried using PLINQ, but it seems the threading overheads actually make it slowers (comes it at 3.48s).

I'm thinking unsafe C# might be the way to go, however, before I go down that road, I'd appreciate any thoughts about how to improve performance?  I haven't done unsafe C# before, so I'm not sure whether it'd be a performance gain?!

```
Console.WriteLine("started");
        var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        long iterations = 0;
        string[] data = new string[5000];
        string[] data2 = new string[5000];
        string[] data3 = new string[5000];

        int ubound = data.GetUpperBound(0);
        for (int i = 0; i <= ubound; i++)
        {
            string d1 = data[i];
            string d2 = data2[i];
            string d3 = data3[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < ubound; j++)
            {
                string e1 = data[j];
                string e2 = data2[j];
                string e3 = data3[j];
                Interlocked.Increment(ref iterations);
            }

            Interlocked.Increment(ref iterations);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Finished {0} iterations in {1} seconds", iterations, sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

Comment: 50,000**2? 2,500,000,000 records? That's a lot for 1.86s

Comment: Does it absolutely need to be multidimensional or could you modify the code to use a 1d array instead?  I suspect that using multiple dimensions may suppress the jitter optimization of removing bounds checks when it is known that bounds cannot be exceeded.

Comment: 1 micro optimization - move the result of `data.GetUpperBound(0)` outside the loops and use the result variable directly.

Comment: haha, no it's 25,000,000 in 1.86s! 50,000² will be the min total number of iterations in the real world.  It does need to be multidimensional, however, that's a good experiment.  I will see whether making it 1d makes any difference. thanks

Comment: Just remember that the string type is immutable. Every one of thoes string assignments is create a new object that has to be created and later destroyed. Also have tou looked at your Garbage collector modes. I think you would definatly want to configure the CLR running this to server GC.

Comment: yep, the outer and inner loops work on the same array.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about GetUpperBound!  Taken me down to 1.2s!

Comment: "Every one of thoes string assignments is create a new object that has to be created and later destroyed". You're sure about that @user957902? That's not what immutability means. The strings in question have already been created. These are just references to those same strings.

Comment: I'd probably have a stab at making a flat array and using modulo maths to address the dimensionality of it.

Comment: The creation of those string objects is just indicative of the later workload.  The inner array workload will be optimized separately.

Comment: @Spender My bad, you are correct. Thoes are just references not new objects in this sample.

Comment: Now at 0.76s by having 3 arrays, rather than 1 2d array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a multidimensional array, go for a flat array and use maths to address it:

```
Console.WriteLine("started");
var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
long iterations = 0;

var width=5000;
var height=3;
string[] data = new string[width*height];
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    string d1 = data[i];
    string d2 = data[width+i];
    string d3 = data[width*2+i];

    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        string e1 = data[j];
        string e2 = data[width+j];
        string e3 = data[width*2+j];
        Interlocked.Increment(ref iterations);
    }
    //});

    Interlocked.Increment(ref iterations);
}
Console.WriteLine("Finished {0} iterations in {1} seconds", iterations, sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

Comment: OK, you win!  I went further by trying to use stackallow and pointer arithmetic, however, I ran out of space on the stack (once I started using some real data). Even looked into the possbility of creating an unmanaged string array, but I don't think it's possible / viable. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are the Interlocked.Increment() calls necessary to represent the actual problem? From the code as you've written it, the largest chunk of time is likely taken by those calls. The calls can be done away with since there is no multithreaded access to the local variable iterations.

Comment: Hi there, that's just in there for when i convert it to multithreaded. thx